# How to return my string value with whitespace

Tags: java, gson, java.util.scanner

How can I modify my main class so that I can receive values without losing the whitespace?

Here is a portion of my main class:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File("C:/User/waithaka/Documents//duka.json")));
while (s.hasNext()) {
    sb.append(s.next());
}
s.close();

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

String jstring = sb.toString();
Result results = gson.fromJson(jstring, Result.class);
List<data> dat = response.getData();
for (data data : dat) {
    System.out.println("The item is " + data.getItem());
}
```

The last line prints the values without whitespace. For example, a value with the string `"Black and yellow"` will be changed to `"Blackandyellow"`.

Comment: I think your problem is in using `Scanner` to read in your file. `Scanner` returns "words" - strings separated by whitespace. The whitespace itself is ommitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem comes from using Scanner, since it may be trimming white spaces. As you are already using, some Google libraries (Gson), I would also use Google's guava, its Files class has a toString() method that will read a whole file to a String:

[Files.toString()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Answer (score 3):

If you look at Scanner.java class you can see white space treated as new line characters.

```
public Scanner(InputStream source) {
        this(new InputStreamReader(source), WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
    }
```

You need to set line separator as

```
s.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

I was able to replicate and fix the problem, below is the code -

JSON

```
{
name:"Stack-overflow",
url:"http://www.stack-overflow   .com"
}
```

And here's the class

```
public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(new File(
                "/Users/chatar/Documents/dev/projects/stack-overflow/stack-overflow/bin/C:/User/waithaka/Documents/duka.json")));

        s.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String nxt = s.next();
            sb.append(nxt);
        }
        s.close();

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        String jstring = sb.toString();
        Result results = gson.fromJson(jstring, Result.class);

        System.out.println("The item is " + results);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can accept more than one answer if all of them works for you!